# Cherry pick works fine for multiple commits, but keeps giving a message "You are in 'detached HEAD' state"

Tags: java, bash, git, shell

I have written a script, which takes 5 inputs:
1) Clone URL
2) BranchName to which the cherry pick needs to be merged
3) The new branch name which needs to be created with all the cherry pick commits
4) The cherryPick commit ids.
5) Dynamically created temp directory in which these operations should happen.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo 'Start Cherry Pick'

cd $5 || exit

echo 'Switched to '$5
git clone $1 .
git checkout -f origin/$2
git checkout -b $3
git cherry-pick $4
git push origin HEAD
echo '***** SUCCESS *****'
```

This works well and creates a new branch on the `$2` with name as `$3` and prints `***** SUCCESS *****`

```
Start Cherry Pick, Switched to C:\Users\******\Local\Temp\ae85a131-f783-4245-a5df-c4a54f6619b02426345661203195835, 
Cloning into '.'..., Updating files:  29% (359/1216), Updating files:  30% (365/1216)Updating files:  31% (377/1216)Updating files:  32%  (1180/1216)Updating files:  98% (1192/1216)Updating files:  99% (1204/1216)Updating files: 100% (1216/1216)Updating files: 100% (1216/1216), done.

Note: switching to 'origin/master'., 
You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental, changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this, state without impacting any branches by switching back to a branch., If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may, do so (now or later) by using -c with the switch command. 
Example:,   git switch -c <new-branch-name>, Or undo this operation with:,   git switch -, Turn off this advice by setting config variable advice.detachedHead to false, 
HEAD is now at 9a97592 Merge pull request #25 from gitUserName/CEAS-243, 
Switched to a new branch 'CEAS-1234', 
[CEAS-1234 ca9e831] should be ahead of master AccountManagerTest.cls,  Date: Mon Apr 6 16:35:56 2020 +0530,  1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-), 
[CEAS-1234 f7ab9df] should be ahead of master AccountProcessorTest.cls,  Date: Tue Apr 7 00:06:26 2020 +0530,  1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-), remote: , 
remote: Create a pull request for 'CEAS-1234' on GitHub by visiting:        , 
remote:      https://github.com/gitUserName/gitRepoName/pull/new/CEAS-1234        , 
remote: , To https://github.com/gitUserName/gitRepoName.git,  * [new branch]      
HEAD -> CEAS-1234, ***** SUCCESS *****]
```

But lets say in any scenario if the script fails, like bad commit ids, or if the branch which is being created already exists, even then the `Success is printed` and even the same message this is printed `You are in 'detached HEAD'....`

Here is the output when script fails:

```
Start Cherry Pick, 
Switched to C:\Users\NAGESI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\b46aebc4-479a-43f0-a333-cebfad5b9e2a945082863319958458, 
Cloning into '.'..., Updating files:  39% (475/1216), Updating files:  40% (487/1216)Updating files:  41% (499/1216)Updating files:  42% (1168/1216)Updating files:  97% (1180/1216)Updating files:  98% (1192/1216)Updating files:  99% (1204/1216)Updating files: 100% (1216/1216)Updating files: 100% (1216/1216), done.
Note: switching to 'origin/master'., 
You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental, changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this, state without impacting any branches by switching back to a branch., If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may, do so (now or later) by using -c with the switch command. Example:,   
git switch -c <new-branch-name>, Or undo this operation with:,   git switch -, Turn off this advice by setting config variable advice.detachedHead to false, 
HEAD is now at 9a97592 Merge pull request #25 from gitUserName/CEAS-243, Switched to a new branch 'CEAS-1234', 
[CEAS-1234 f1e152e] should be ahead of master AccountManagerTest.cls,  Date: Mon Apr 6 16:35:56 2020 +0530,  1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-), 
[CEAS-1234 03c5681] should be ahead of master AccountProcessorTest.cls,  Date: Tue Apr 7 00:06:26 2020 +0530,  1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-), To https://github.com/gitUserName/gitRepoName.git,  ! [rejected]        
HEAD -> CEAS-1234 (non-fast-forward), 
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/gitUserName/gitRepoName.git', hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind, hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g., hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again., hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details., 
***** SUCCESS *****]
```

**So how can I print `success` only when the script is running fine and print error and error message if anything fails. 
Second, how to get rid of `You are in 'detached HEAD' state.....` message.**

I tried : `$?` but it seems to only return exit code, so that may not be helpful much, in case of error and error message.

Just FYI : I am invoking this script from Java Ant Launcher:
Where my target is :

```
<target name="git_multi_cherry_pick">
    <echo message="START: MultiMerge"/>
    <exec executable="C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe" osfamily="windows" failonerror="true">
        <arg value="${gitMultiCherryPick}"/>
        <arg value="${gitCloneURL}"/>
        <arg value="${gitBranchName}"/>
        <arg value="${gitNewBranchName}"/>
        <arg value="${cherryPickIds}"/>
        <arg value="${gitDirectory}"/>
    </exec>
    <exec executable="/bin/bash" osfamily="unix" failonerror="true">
        <arg value="${gitMultiCherryPick}"/>
        <arg value="${gitCloneURL}"/>
        <arg value="${gitBranchName}"/>
        <arg value="${gitNewBranchName}"/>
        <arg value="${cherryPickIds}"/>
        <arg value="${gitDirectory}"/>
    </exec>
</target>
```

And code to launch this target is

```
Map<String, String> propertiesMap = new HashMap<>();
String uuid = String.valueOf(UUID.randomUUID());
Path tempDirectory = Files.createTempDirectory(uuid);
ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
InputStream buildXml = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("build/build.xml");
InputStream gitCherryPick = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("build/git-multi-cherry-pick.sh");
File buildFile = ConsumerHandler.stream2file(buildXml, "build", ".xml");
File cherryPick = ConsumerHandler.stream2file(gitCherryPick, "git-multi-cherry-pick", ".sh");
propertiesMap.put("gitMultiCherryPick", cherryPick.getName());
propertiesMap.put("gitCloneURL", "https://myGitRepo.git");
propertiesMap.put("gitBranchName", "master");
propertiesMap.put("gitNewBranchName", "CEAS-1234");
propertiesMap.put("cherryPickIds", "903f59d668e62e9950cb0616d39defde10a4730c 67faf443bf96e4b51f1d5eb0f93559d8c022e482");
propertiesMap.put("gitDirectory", tempDirectory.toFile().getPath());
List<String> sf_build = AntExecutor.executeAntTask(buildFile.getPath(), "git_multi_cherry_pick", propertiesMap);
```

And `sf_build` returns with the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script uses:

```
git checkout -f origin/$2
```

right after the `git clone` step.  Why did you use this remote-tracking name?  That is why you are in "detached HEAD" mode.

There is nothing incorrect about using detached HEAD mode, and the rest of your script handles it, but if you don't want to use detached HEAD mode, don't ask for detached HEAD mode.

The opposite of detached HEAD mode is when you have an attached HEAD, i.e., when you are on a branch name.  You would do this by:

- creating a new branch name, pointing to the same commit as `origin/$2`, then
- switching to that branch name

which you can do in one step with:

```
git checkout -B $2 origin/$2
```

You can remove the `-f` here as there should be no reason to use `-f` at all.  The only reason to use uppercase `B` here is in case `$2` is the branch name that the remote repository recommended, so that you are already on branch `$2` like this.  If the remote repository recommends `master` and you will never use `master`, you can use `git checkout -b $2 origin/$2` instead.

If you like, you can use `git clone -b $2` to kick the whole thing off, so that your clone operation ends with the equivalent of `git checkout -b $2 origin/$2`.

> But lets say in any scenario if the script fails, like bad commit ids, or if the branch which is being created already exists ...

(As already noted, no branch is being created.)

It's wise to check the exit status of *each* Git command:

```
git clone ... || exit
git checkout ... || exit
```

and so on.  To do the equivalent, without the repeated `|| exit` steps, you can set the `e` option:

```
set -e
```

before the series of commands, each of which will now cause the entire script to quit as soon as any command fails.

Answer (score 1):

You are checking out a remote branch (`origin/whatever`). Git is more than happy to comply but a local branch is not created at that point... you are left in `detached HEAD` state.... and then you run your magic and do `git push origin HEAD` and I think your are missing the target branch. Is it rather `git push origin HEAD:$2`? Finally, do not trust std or err output to tell if the operation went well or not. Use the exit code of the execution to know if it was ok (0 = ok. Anything not 0 = not ok).

Comment: But shouldn't `git push origin HEAD` push the new branch which got created via `git checkout -b $3`